# While (sexo!='hombre' || sexo!='mujer') no acepta mis condiciones

Tags: java, while

Existe algún error de sintaxis que no me esté permitiendo validar que sexo sea distinto a `h` o `m`?

extracto:

> Al ejecutar el código, el ciclo no se interrumpe aunque el usuario escriba h o m.

Código:

```
            System.out.print("Ingrese sexo (h)ombre, (m)ujer");
            char sexo=in.next().charAt(0);
            while (sexo!='h'|| sexo!='m') {
                System.out.println("Solo h o m");
                sexo=in.next().charAt((0));
            }
```

Salida en Terminal:

```
Ingrese sexo (h)ombre, (m)ujer
h
Solo h o m
m
Solo h o m
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

El error está en la condición

```
while (sexo!='h'|| sexo!='m') {// Esta condición siempre se cumple
    System.out.println("Solo h o m");
    sexo=in.next().charAt((0));
}
```

`while (sexo!='h'|| sexo!='m')` Por qué siempre se cumple? Miremos los siguientes casos:

1. `sexo = h` --> `sexo != 'h'` ? No, pero... `sexo != 'm'`? Si, la condición se cumple
2. `sexo = m` --> `sexo != 'h'` ? Si, la condición se cumple

Como ves, siempre se cumple al menos una de las dos, y como usas un `or`, da igual cual se cumpla, mientras que una de las dos se cumpla, con lo cual, seguirá repitiéndose.

Lo que necesitas es `while (sexo!='h' && sexo!='m')`: Siempre que sexo sea distinto de 'h' **Y** sexo sea distinto de 'm' también. Así en el momento en que una de las dos sea verdad, ya no entrará.

Te añado un pequeño ejemplo en javascript para que lo veas:

```js
let sexo = 'h';
//Uso ifs para evitar un loop infinito ya que es un ejemplo muy breve
if(sexo != 'h' || sexo != 'm'){
    console.log('Esta condición SIEMPRE se cumple, así que esto se imprimirá.');
}
if(sexo != 'h' && sexo != 'm'){
    console.log('Esta condición actualmente no se cumple, así que esto NO se imprimirá.');
}
```

Comment: agradezco la respuesta, me sirvió mucho.

Answer (score 2):

el operador logico '||' lo que hace es comprobar si una de las condiciones es verdadera y en ese caso devuelve true, Entonces en tu codigo estas comprobando si (sexo!='h'|| sexo!='m'), como sexo no puede ser h y m al mismo tiempo esa condicion siempre arrojara verdadero y por tanto nunca saldra del while debes cambiar el operador logico '||' por '&&' que lo que hace es comprobar que las dos condiciones sean verdaderas, entonces tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
 System.out.print("Ingrese sexo (h)ombre, (m)ujer");
            char sexo=in.next().charAt(0);
            while (sexo!='h' && sexo!='m') {
                System.out.println("Solo h o m");
                sexo=in.next().charAt((0));
            }
```

Mucha suerte

Comment: agradezco la respuesta, me sirvió mucho.

Answer (score -2):

Hay dos fallos, primero estas evaluando ello con un `While()`por ende si tu programa llega a correr bien evaluara que la variable `Char sexo` y si no es o H o M se ejecutará infinitamente es decir entra en un loop infinito y el segundo error es que no estas usando espacios, debes repasar sintaxis y codigo limpio. te dejo la solucion:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sexo = "a";
    if (sexo != "h" || sexo != "m" ){
      System.out.println("solo se pueden (H) o (M)");
      //resto del código
}
```

}
}

Comment: No se ejecuta infinitamente, dado que dentro del bucle está reasignando la variable que da la salida del bucle, con lo cual en cuanto el usuario ingrese 'h' o 'm', saldrá del bucle, siempre y cuando la lógica del while sea correcta, por supuesto.

Comment: Creo que esta bien evaluado el while, porque lo que el quiere es que sigan escribiendo mientras que no coloquen h o m, la cosa es su condicion, es con && para evaluar que no pongan otro que no sean esos 2.